# After first REST call, user and password in the OSecurityShared class of Graph are null

Tags: java, rest, graph, transactions, orientdb

Good morning,

I'm trying tu use transactional OrientDB graph.

here i create my graph instance :

```
@Autowired
OrientGraphFactory graphFactory;

private static FramedGraphFactory framedFactory;

public FramedTransactionalGraph<OrientGraph> getGraph() {
    OrientGraph instance = graphFactory.getTx();
    if (framedFactory == null) {
        framedFactory = new FramedGraphFactory();
    }
    FramedTransactionalGraph<OrientGraph> framedGraph = framedFactory.create(instance);
    return framedGraph;
}

public void setGraphFactory(OrientGraphFactory graphFactory) {
    this.graphFactory = graphFactory;
}
```

In my DAOImpl I call one and only one instance of it:

```
 private FramedTransactionalGraph<OrientGraph> getGraph() {
    if (graphTx == null) {
        graphTx = graphFactoryTx.getGraph();
    } else {
        return graphTx;
    }
    return graphTx;
}
```

Here my applicationContext.xml (for the sake of clarity)

```
 <bean id="graphTx" class="it.wedoo.mmoutlet.graph.factory.GraphFactoryTx">
    <property  name="graphFactory" value="com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="frameFactory" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ServiceLocatorFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
    <property name="serviceLocatorInterface" value="it.wedoo.mmoutlet.graph.dao.FrameFactory" />
</bean>    
<bean id="orientGraphFactory" class="com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphFactory" >
    <constructor-arg name="iURL" value="plocal:${orientdb.path}"/>
    <property name="transactional" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Where I call for the first time via REST my custom method all is ok, and data correctly written on the graph, but the second time (with the same REST call), user and password are null.

Here the error raised :

```
{
"errors": {
    "500": {
        "causes": {
            "runtime": [
                "User or password not valid for database: 'db'"
            ]
        }
    }
},
"empty": false
```

}

Can someone help me please?

Regards, Stefano

Answer (score 0):

Seems a security problem because by default it uses admin/admin as user + password, but in your case seems you changed it. Try this:

```
<bean id="orientGraphFactory" class="com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphFactory" >
    <constructor-arg name="iURL" value="plocal:${orientdb.path}"/>
    <constructor-arg name="iUser" value="admin"/>
    <constructor-arg name="iPassword" value="mypasswd"/>
    <property name="transactional" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Where mypasswd is your password.